Two browser stack sessions are triggering for a single test execution
I have Appium + WebdriverIO set up to run mobile test automations and tests are executing at BrowserStack.
I have written my tests are at feature files as below.
Feature: Home verification

Scenario: Validate home page content for a guest user
  Given I launch XXXXXXXXXXX
  When I will XXXXXXX
  Then I will XXXXXXX

When ever I start testing above feature file I can see there are two sessions triggering at BrowserStack one after another.

1st session is for Feature name and it just opens the app and
closing the app. (Test will mark as pass).
2nd session is for the actual scenario.

So can someone explain why its behaving like this and is there any possibility to stop creating the 1st session.Because its not doing anything, just open the app and closing.
I have set dryRun: false, under my cucumberOpts. but still its creating 2 sessions.
Any solution?
